# CakePhp model name conventions

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakePhP,

```
$this->CallDetail->save($data);
```

Database table name is `callDetails`

and the class code is

```
class CallDetail extends AppModel {

    var $name = "CallDetail";


}
```

However CallDetail is not working, what should i change the model name to

Comment: this should work. Could you please provide us the error message?

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description. That being said, **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions**

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain Call to a member function save() on a non-object  meaning the Table is not being read .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you do not load your model. First you have to load your model in your controller. There are two way to load model

One is [loadModel](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::loadModel)

```
$this->loadModel('Article');
```

Another is [$uses](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses) variable

```
public $uses = array('Article');
```

**Update**

Or you can use [$useTable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable) to specify table name

```
public $useTable = 'exmp'; // This model uses a database table 'exmp'
```

Comment: crap, the name was incorrect, but now this function is Table call_details for model CallDetail was not found in datasource default. my table name is callDetails

Comment: ok by some googling i found the solution added     public $useTable = 'callDetails';

Comment: ok than I update my answer with this data so that in future other user can benefited.